# Cache Reset DBResource Provider

Tags: c#

I have used custom SQL DBResource Provider for globalisation. I found once a page has visited then it query database and cache it into `_ResourceCache`.
When I change the database then it displays the label from the cache though the database is changed.

Please anybody help me how to reset the resource cache (`_ResourceCache = null`) even when the database is changed for all category?

I know this is an old question, but I didn't find any proper solution to fix my issue.